# Awk command not working with OR condition

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am using below `awk` command

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=",";} $9=="Consumer" && $4!="" && ($12!="" OR $13!="")  {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16}' TEL_DATA_JUL2016_fxtcupd1.TXT
```

Where I want at least one field from 12 or 13 should be not null but command is not giving desired result.

Can anybody explain what's the problem in the above command.

Thanks

Comment: Not `OR`. It should be `||`.

Comment: Thanks @sat u save my life :)

Answer (score 1):

Logical OR operator should be `||`. Not `OR`. Your `awk` should be,

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=","} $9=="Consumer" && $4!="" && ($12!="" || $13!="") {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16}' file
```